# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when solution is opened

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project, solution

We are using a third-party component that crashes Visual Studio 2010 when it is viewed on a designer. This in itself was not a deal breaker, as we wrote the layout code by hand.

However, last time the designer of this component was viewed by accident and Visual Studio crashed, the [Design] file was saved as open, and now whenever VS is launched and the project opened, the designer is opened by default and then Visual Studio crashes.

I have deleted all *.suo and *.user files, but somehow Visual Studio still remembers which files were open last, making it impossible to open the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the code in the designer file, open the solution, the uncomment it.

First, **make a backup of the file** (if you don't already have one in source control), in case the designer regenerates it.